# Ghost filter posts by tag = slug name

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm writing a theme and I want to get all post tagged with the slug of any specific page by default

like myblog/page1 
will return all post taged page1

when i do

```
{{#get "posts" filter="tags:page1" order="slug asc"}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
      <p>{{@number}}" </p>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

I get my post and everything is fine

but when I add the #post context to get the tag dynamically it doesn't work

I have tried :

```
{{#post}}
{{#get "posts" order="slug asc"}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
        {{#has tag=@slug}}
             <p>{{@number}}" </p>
        {{/has}}
    {{/foreach}}

{{/get}}
{{/post}}
```

and

```
{{#post}}
{{#get "posts" filter="tags:@slug" order="slug asc"}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
      <p>{{@number}}" </p>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
{{/post}}
```

without any success.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the command line prompt? It displays error messages with regards to filters used in the theme. This would be a good place to start.

Comment: @user2272296 yes, no error for both versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok everyone, actually it's pretty simple

```
{{#post}}
{{#get "posts" filter="tags:{{slug}}" order="slug asc"}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
      <p>{{@number}}" </p>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
{{/post}}
```

in the post context , use the slug of the post , only trick is to put handlebars inside handlebars